# Is the mathematical truth 1+1=2 analogous to the conservation of energy?

Tags: energy-conservation, conservation-laws, mathematics

They seem to express the same concept in different fields.

Comment: 1+1=2 is a statement about natural numbers. Depending on how deep you like your axioms it can actually be taken as a reasonable definition of the number 2. What exactly is the "concept" similar to energy that you feel this expresses?

Answer (score 4):

1+1=2 follows from the axioms of mathematics. There are different sets of axioms, one example is Peano axioms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms .

Mathematically, the conservation of energy can be seen as a consequence of the symmetry of physical laws under shift in time. That said, a theory without time shift symmetry doesn't conserve energy. The conservation of energy can be derived from a more general concept, the principle of least action which is usually taken as a postulate.

So no, at least I don't see any connection between the two statements.

Answer (score 1):

No.

1+1=2 is basically a trivial truth that is by definition true (In the correct context of course. You know what I/O.P. means. Please don't be picky here). An important point is that both quantities on the two sides of the equations are completely static and cannot be changed.

However, the conservation of energy is far from trivial and expresses a conservation of an important physical quantity, relating between initial and final potential and kinetic energies, and can be utilized to conduct very non-trivial calculations.

And conservation of energy is not even true in certain fields or theories of physics(say, GR), or has unclear meanings.

Comment: 1+1=2 is not trivial at all from abstract point view (but it is from intuitive point of view), it needs hundreds of pages to be proven from ZFC axioms!

Comment: @TMS Hundreds of pages? I think that's an exaggeration. Just notice that applying the successor operation on 1 (1 + 1) is equal to the second integer (2) by identifying elements. Hundreds of pages!?

Comment: No, no exaggeration at all, check here http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2011/07/why-did-112-take-russell-and-whitehead.html

Comment: @TMS So was my proof above correct? I'm using the ready-made definitions of +, =, 1, and 2. I don't think that counts as cheating.

Comment: @TMS: I don't quite see how that link supports you argument. How long you take to "prove it" depends on the axioms, and (I'm pretty sure) in ZFC you get it fairly straight away.

Comment: @namehere: 1+1=2 has no relation to physics except from intuitive point of view, and your statement regarding GR is wrong, energy is always conserved, it's fundamental as 1+1=2 it self.

Comment: @TMS No. Energy isn't conserved in GR. Basically in general manifolds there is no appropriate notion of energy as there are no timelike killing vectors. The local energy-momentum tensor conservation includes additional terms from the connection so I don't accept that either.

Comment: @NickKidman: ZFC is currently the "Main Stream" Axioms (not sure how mathematicians name it) because they can build the whole math currently we use, and if you can do it better than Russell, then it's good for you, being sure is not enough.

Comment: @TMS Can ZFC build the axioms in other formulations of set theory incompatible with ZFC?

Comment: @namehere: of curse in GR by energy I mean't the whole energy-momentum tensor, and by conservation very roughly speaking (in the context of the main question) we mean it's don't comes from nothing, anyway if you meant by energy the $T_{00}$ then I agree with you, and you need a mathematician for the second question.

Comment: @TMS: I think it follows from the peano axioms pretty quickly too.

Comment: @namehere: No, but it can inspire. The relationships between different ideas of Set Theories like NBG, ZFC ETCS etc are complex and subtle.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: Let's raise this question at MathSE to be sure.

Comment: @TMS: Sure, go ahead. I think the peano axioms (1888) were historically antecedent to ZFC (1908), and you show that you can get the peano axioms from ZFC.

Comment: @namehere: Actually, thinking about it I think you could. You're better off asking that question on math overflow. I think the key question is what would be meant by incompatibility.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I mean those that are inconsistent with ZFC

Comment: @namehere: Some set theorists are meditating about a 'multiverse' of set theories, what role ZFC plays in that, and what could be meant by logic & consistency in that setup; I'm not qualified to answer. There are (paraconsistent) logics in which inconsistencies are contained. Theres a whole world of different logics too. Remember that ZFC doesn't come along by itself, it also needs a logic too. I think your question is a good one, but you need a mathematician seriously interested in those concerns.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, 1+1=2 is not a "truth", but a statement valid only under certain algebras. For binary numbers 1+1=10 whereas 1+1=11 for algebras satisfying the axiom A+B=AB.

The statement of conservation of energy is a law of nature and does not depend on the axioms/algebra chosen. Moreover, the statement 1+1=2 is also valid for non-conserved quantities such as entropy. For instance "1" could be (adding the correct units) the production of entropy in a given system and the other "1" (adding the correct units) the flow of entropy received from surrounds. Then the total variation of entropy would be "2" (adding the correct units), but entropy has not been conserved.

Comment: anyone care to put forward an experiment DISproving 1+1=2 as a physical constant?  :P

Answer (score -2):

I would agree. The key word is 'analogous'. He isn't positing an identity.

1+1=2: Both sides are/look different, yet they are expressions of the same thing. A 'change' has been accomplished that moves 1+1 to 2, (or from 2 to 1+1), yet they remain the same.

Conservation of mass, is built on the principle that 1+1=2. If mass is made of indivisible atoms, this simply expresses it.

After Einstein, we now know that this should be mass-energy conservation. The counting has become more complex.

Its really more of a philosophical/historical/intellectual psychology kind of question.

One of the reasons as to why we view the principle of conservation of mass-energy, as of fundamental importance (in addition to its use as an explanatory/calculational device) is because as some of the other posters have pointed out, in the right axiomatic framework, 1+1=2 is tautology. It helps underline the fundamental position that conservation principles take.